# CMD/Batch Get Handle to Open App?

Tags: excel, batch-file, cmd, dos

I've just made a batch file that launches a new instance of an application (Excel) and then opens a file with this instance.

However, I would like to be able to store a config file on each users computer that holds a preference setting.

The setting would tell the batch file to either open a new instance, or launch the file with an existing instance of Excel (if available).  I'm good on the program flow, just want to know the commands for getting a handle to an open instance of the app.  Is this possible using DOS commands, or do I need to look at designing a front loader with Excel or some other program?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to get access to a running application instance from a batch or .cmd file. You can do it via VBScript or PowerShell, though.

Comment: the most precise information that you can get via pure batch script is with wmic : `wmic process where name="excel.exe" get  /format:csv`

Answer (score 2):

What if you just execute the Excel-File? 
If no excel is running, one instance will start, 
if an excel is running, this Excel is used to view the file. :)

Or maybe a check via TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME EQ EXCEL.EXE" could help to check whenever an instance is running or not:

```
TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME EQ EXCEL.EXE" | FINDSTR /I "EXCEL.EXE" >NUL 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :NotFound
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO :Found
```

Kind regards

Edited w/ Findstr & errorhandling.

Comment: Nice try. Unfortunately tasklist does not set errorlevel (on Vista). But if you show how to get and test the output I'll upvote (I'll test it later on Windows 7).

Comment: Sorry. My fault ^.^ 
But i got it to work w/ following code: 
TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME EQ EXCEL.EXE" | FINDSTR "EXCEL.EXE" >NUL 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :NotFound
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO :Found

Comment: You should use `FINDSTR /I` and it ok. Please edit your post with that answer.